# Unexpected sizeof auto variable assigned to lambda

Tags: c++, c++20

I am running the below code and I am getting unexpected results:

```
int main()
{
    int val = 10;

    auto a = [&]() {return val + 53;};
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl; //OUTPUTS 8
  
}
```

I got to know that lambdas basically decompose to functors. So I thought sizeof for `a` should return 4 (size of member variable reference for `val`). But this is not the case.

I tried cpp insights to see if there is additional member variables, but I could only find the member variable reference for `val`. `a` is being expanded to anonymous class

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Its taking `val` by _reference_. References are internally very likely implemented like pointers are - hence 8 (as pointers are 8 bytes on modern 64bit systems).

Comment: @MikeVine I tried printing out reference size but it is printing as 4: `int &ref = val;`

Comment: `sizeof(T&)` is `sizeof(T)` - the reference is ignored. See second comment in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof - _When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type_. Try putting the reference in a struct and print out the size of the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we replace the lambda with an actual functor you'll see the same result:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Lambda
{
    int & val;
    int operator()()
    {
        return val + 53;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int val = 10;

    auto a = Lambda{val};
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;  //OUTPUTS 8
  
}
```

The lambda is storing a reference, not the value. References are usually the same size as a pointer so will normally be 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform.

If we capture by value the size is `4` as you expect:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Lambda
{
    int val;
    int operator()()
    {
        return val + 53;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int val = 10;

    auto a = Lambda{val};
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
  
}
```